Empty blank Swagger docs for newly created microservice project using Jhipster
Overview of the issue
I created a new microservice project using jHipster 8, Keycloak and docker. The project contains the gateway and a microservice contanerised with docker. I accessed the project on http://localhost:8080. It works fine with the exemption that Swagger docs on this url http://localhost/admin/docs does not show anything. It is blank. This is strange and I sought the support of more knowledgable experts here.
Developing locally, Swagger docs did not show at http://localhost:8080/admin/docs
JHipster Version(s)
8.6.0
JHipster configuration
application {
  config {
    baseName gateway
    packageName com.christdoes.gateway
    applicationType gateway
    authenticationType oauth2
    buildTool maven
    cacheProvider hazelcast
    databaseType sql
    clientFramework angularX
    clientPackageManager npm
    devDatabaseType h2Memory
    prodDatabaseType postgresql
    enableHibernateCache true
    enableSwaggerCodegen true
    enableTranslation true
    languages [nl, en, fr, de, es]
    messageBroker kafka
    nativeLanguage en
    searchEngine elasticsearch
    serverPort 8080
    serviceDiscoveryType consul
    skipClient false
    skipServer false
    skipUserManagement false
    testFrameworks [cucumber]
    websocket no
  }
  entities *
}

application {
  config {
    baseName notaries
    packageName com.christdoes.notaries
    applicationType microservice
    authenticationType oauth2
    buildTool maven
    cacheProvider hazelcast
    databaseType sql
    devDatabaseType h2Memory
    dtoSuffix DTO
    enableHibernateCache true
    enableSwaggerCodegen true
    enableTranslation true
    languages [nl, en, fr, de, es]
    messageBroker kafka
    nativeLanguage en
    prodDatabaseType postgresql
    reactive true
    searchEngine elasticsearch
    serverPort 8081
    serviceDiscoveryType consul
    skipClient true
    skipServer false
    skipUserManagement false
    testFrameworks [cucumber]
    websocket no
  }
  entities ...
}

Entity configuration(s) entityName.json files generated in the .jhipster directory
JHipster configuration, a .yo-rc.json file generated in the root folder
.yo-rc.json file
JHipster configuration for gateway not found
JHipster configuration for notaries not found
Environment and Tools
java version "22.0.1" 2024-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 22.0.1+8.1 (build 22.0.1+8-jvmci-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 22.0.1+8.1 (build 22.0.1+8-jvmci-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-146)

node: v20.16.0
npm: 10.8.1

Docker version 26.1.4, build 5650f9b

Browsers and Operating System
Google Chrome & MacOS M3

MacOS M3


[*] Checking this box is mandatory (this is just to show you read everything)

